# how to run obfs4 in ubuntu as a client?

Tags: obfs4

I wanted to use OBFS4 as a client and not as a server in ubuntu 14.0.4,how can I do it?

there were a topic like this on the forum but he wanted to use it as a server not client.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the Tor Browser alpha release, it includes the obfs4 binary and allows you to configure it easily.